# .NET Convert array of implicitly convertible types

Tags: .net, arrays, casting

Let's assume we have two ref types: `A` and `B`, and A implements the implicit cast operator (to B):

```
class A
{
    private B b;
    public static implicit operator B(A a) { return a.b; }
}
class B
{
}
```

What's the best (concise and/or fast) way to convert an array of `A` to an array of `B` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that works and is reasonably straight-forward is using Linq:

```
A[] a = new A[5];//initialize elements
B[] b = a.Select(anA => (B)anA).ToArray();
```

However using Linq's Cast<> method does NOT work: ([see why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14523530/11545))

```
B[] b2 = a.Cast<B>.ToArray();//throws InvalidCastException
```

---

Update: here's one that doesn't use Linq:

```
B[] b = Array.ConvertAll(a, elem => (B) elem);
```

This could work in pre-lambda .NET 2.0 using a more verbose approach:

```
B[] b = Array.ConvertAll(a, 
            new Converter<A, B>(delegate(A elem) { return (B) elem; }));
```

...and possibly using the shorter version:

```
B[] b = Array.ConvertAll(a, delegate(A elem) { return (B) elem; });
```

Comment: +1, and as an interesting aside, `.Cast<T>` accepts an `IEnumerable` (as opposed to `IEnumerable<T>`) which is why the cast fails; it only sees an Enumerable of `Object`s not `A`s. `.Select()` remains the best approach.

Comment: @Brad Regarding .Cast<> So what? What it does under the covers is trying to cast an instance (of object, yes) to (in this case) B. I spawned [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14523530/11545) to delve deeper into the subject.

Comment: Was that a question to me, or a general comment?

Comment: @Brad It was both, I guess. Regarding your initial comment, I'm missing the relevance of Cast having a "vanilla" `IEnumerable` parameter. (Isn't it the whole point of `Cast` to take something type-less (non-generic) and transform it to something with a specified type?)

Comment: Yes, but the runtime doesn't take in to account your `operator` methods of the custom object when it performs the cast, only the `boxing/unboxing` conversion. (And in this instance `A` is being boxed as an `Object` because of how generic `IEnumerable` is to `IEnumerable<T>`.)

Comment: @Brad A lot clearer now - so +1 for taking the time to explain!