# Why does the Linq Cast<> helper not work with the implicit cast operator?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, implicit-conversion, coercion

*Please read to the end before deciding of voting as duplicate...*

I have a type that implements an `implicit cast` operator to another type:

```
class A
{
    private B b;
    public static implicit operator B(A a) { return a.b; }
}
class B
{
}
```

Now, implicit and explicit casting work just fine:

```
B b = a;
B b2 = (B)a;
```

...so how come Linq's `.Cast<>` doesn't?

```
A[] aa = new A[]{...};
var bb = aa.Cast<B>();  //throws InvalidCastException
```

Looking at the source code for `.Cast<>`, there's not much magic going on: a few special cases if the parameter really is a `IEnumerable<B>`, and then:

```
foreach (object obj in source) 
    yield return (T)obj; 
    //            ^^ this looks quite similar to the above B b2 = (B)a;
```

So why does *my* explicit cast work, but not the one inside `.Cast<>`?

Does the compiler sugar-up my explicit cast ?

PS. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/808725/11545) but I don't think its answers really explain what's going on.

Comment: Even if _"its answers wouldn't really explain what's going on"_ you should not ask duplicate questions ;)

Comment: @Tim and how would you suggest I improve the answers of a topic (that I don't know the answer to) except for asking a better question?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, if this question gets better answers, maybe the other one should be closed as a dup of this?

Comment: I don't know what's the correct way to handle this. I often see questions getting closed where the answers are better than in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @tim Apparently the consensus on meta is to merge the questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1375/136203 - I've flagged this question, let's see what happens :)

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu: More this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55251/opinions-on-closing-an-older-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-question

Comment: `var bb = aa.Select(x => (B)x);` ftw, maybe with a `.ToArray()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer would be simply: the `Cast<T>` method doesn't support custom conversion operators.

In the first example:

```
B b = a;
B b2 = (B)a;
```

the compiler can see this `B(A a)` operator during static analysis; the compiler interprets this as a static `call` to your custom operator method. In the second example:

```
foreach (object obj in source) 
    yield return (T)obj;
```

that has *no knowledge* of the operator; this is implemented via `unbox.any` (which is the same as `castclass` if `T` is a ref-type).

There is also a third option: if you went via `dynamic`, the runtime implementation tries to mimic compiler rules, so this *will* find the operator ... but not as part of the C#-to-IL compile step:

```
dynamic b = a; // note that `dynamic` here is *almost* the same as `object`
B b2 = b;
```

Comment: You're right. I tried this, and it throws: `B b = (B)(object)a;` I assume it's because I'm hiding `a`'s real type in the static context...

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu yes; by going via `object`, it becomes a simple `castclass`, and `castclass` *does not support custom operators*.

Comment: BTW. I think in your last example you meant `B b2 = (B) b ;`

Comment: Adding to this, you can cast through the inheritance tree, so ultimately *everything* can be casted to `object`. Thus `(new DerivedType[] { ... }).Cast<ParentType>()` always works, and `(new ParentType[] { new DerivedType(...), ... })).Cast<DerivedType>()` works when all the elements are the derived type.

Answer (score 16):

> So why my explicit cast work, and the one inside .Cast<> doesn't?

Your explicit cast knows *at compile time* what the source and destination types are. The compiler can spot the explicit conversion, and emit code to invoke it.

That *isn't* the case with generic types. Note that this isn't specific to `Cast` or LINQ in general - you'd see the same thing if you tried a simple `Convert` method:

```
public static TTarget Convert<TSource, TTarget>(TSource value)
{
    return (TTarget) value;
}
```

That will *not* invoke any user-defined conversions - or even conversions from (say) `int` to `long`. It will *only* perform reference conversions and boxing/unboxing conversions. It's just part of how generics work.

Comment: So should an explicit operator always be defined to complement an implicit operator? Is there a reason that implicit operators don't "implicitly" include explicit conversion?

Comment: Is there a way to make it work? It would be pretty useful in certain scenarios - like when working with Oracles stupid types that don't even implement `IConvertible`...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: The closest you could come would be to use `dynamic`, I suspect.

Comment: @WillVousden: implicit operators can be called explicitly. Adding an explicit operator to the sample code above wouldn't change the observed behavior.

Comment: @WillVousden: It has nothing to do with whether the conversion is explicit or implicit - it's *only* because your conversion is a user-defined one. That simply won't be used by a generic cast operation.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ha, good idea. Never thought about using `dynamic` in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerable.Cast<T>` is a .Net framework method and has a behavior that makes sense in all of the .Net languages that call it.

See also, Ander Hejlsberg's reply on [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/fe6c7c84-5f99-484a-99de-b331d4c88b76/).

---

> Does the compiler sugar-up my explicit cast ?

What you call an "implicit cast operator" is actually an "[implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)".  It's a common mistake.

C# allows you to specify conversions using the casting syntax.  When this happens, you are using a different instance (converting), not changing the reference to the same instance (casting).