# C#: Can't cast<myType> with implicit conversion

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, casting, type-conversion

I have an implicit conversion method in one of my classes.

```
public static implicit operator MobileTag(DetailGroup dg)
{
    return new MobileTag { Id = dg.ID, Name = dg.Name, Answers = dg.Details };
}
```

This works just fine with a List if I foreach through it:

```
foreach (var tag in tagsThisEvent)
{
    ev.EventTags.Add(tag);   // lookin' good !!
}
```

But then if I use the generic Linq Cast method I get an InvalidCastException:

```
ev.EventTags = tagsThisEvent.Cast<MobileTag>().ToList(); // ftl !!
```

I can't F11 into it to see what it is balking on. Any suggestions?

When is it okay to use List.Cast().ToList() ??

Comment: What is the declaration of `tagsThisEvent`?  Mouseover the `var` in the foreach statement. What type is it resolving to?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523530/why-does-the-linq-cast-helper-not-work-with-the-implicit-cast-operator