# Ienumerable.cast to ValueTuple InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, exception, valuetuple

I have this class named `Point2D` having two properties `X` and `Y`. This class has an implicit conversion to ValueTuple `(double x, double y)`

My problem comes when I cast `List<Point2D>()` to `List<(double x, double y)>()` using `Linq` `Ienumerable.Cast<T>()`, it gives me `InvalidCastException`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Example

```
public class Point2D
{
public Point2D(double x, double y)
{X=x;
Y=y;
}
 public double X {get;}
public double Y {get;}

public static implicit operator (double x, double y) (Point2D point)=> (point.X, point.Y);

public static implicit operator Point2D((double x, double y) point) => new Point2D( point.x, point.y);
}
```

There's the class, so if I do this

```
var points=new List<Point2D>(){(1,2),(2,3)};
```

I get cast exception if I do this

```
var list = points.Cast<(double x, double y)>().ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Linq Cast<> helper not work with the implicit cast operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523530/why-does-the-linq-cast-helper-not-work-with-the-implicit-cast-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are defining your operators, you are defining custom *conversion* operators, not *cast* operators.  Custom *conversion* operators are only applied at compile time from one static type to another (which generally means they can't be used in generic methods).  The "Cast" enumerable method is only applying *cast* operations (as the name implies).

It's not possible to create custom casting operators (casting is a thing only the language/runtime can mess around with).

If you change `points.Cast<(double x, double y)>()` to `points.Select>(p => ((double x, double y))p)`, that will instead invoke your custom cast operator (though it looks pretty crazy with all those parenthesis, but the are needed to convert to the named tuple).